# VARIABLE JS A PHP

Tags: php, javascript, base-de-datos, date

Estoy intentando colocar la fecha usando `js` y después pasarla a una variable `PHP` para agregarla a mi base de datos, realmente no sé si esta bien lo que hago, experimente con un poco de información que encontré.
Esto es un fragmento del código :

```
<script>
    var meses = new Array("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre");
    var diasSemana = new Array("Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado");
    var f = new Date();
    var fecha_completa = (diasSemana[f.getDay()] + ", " + f.getDate() + " de " + meses[f.getMonth()] + " de " + f.getFullYear());
</script>

<?php
$fecha= "<script> document.writeln(fecha_completa); </script>";
?>
```

Cuando coloco un `echo $fecha` si me imprime la fecha correctamente, sin embargo me gustaría que ese dato se guardara en la `BD` pero se guarda esto : `<script> document.writeln(fecha_completa); </script>`

Esta es mi sentencia para insertar a la `BD`:

```
$resultado = $conn->query("
    INSERT INTO datos_usuarios (
        nombre,
        apellido,
        curp,
        curso,
        horas,
        email,
        fecha
    ) VALUES (
        '$nombre',
        '$apellido',
        '$curp',
        '$curso',
        '$horas',
        '$email',
        '$fecha'
    )");
```

Comment: Y por qué quieres almacenar la fecha con ese formato?

Comment: Porque esa fecha al momento de insertar genera un PDF y es necesario que la fecha este en ese formato

Comment: Creo que lo estás enfocando mal, guardar una fecha en ese formato no te permitirá operaciones con ellas después, por otro lado le estás dando a tu base de datos la responsabilidad que no le corresponde que es la de guardar a modo formateados los datos cuando eso lo deberías programar tu al momento de mostrar este dato a través de una consulta, me parece una mala práctica que a la larga te traerá más dificultades

Comment: Tu sabrías como hacerlo? Me podrías ayudar?

Comment: Consejos rápidos, tu base de datos debe guardar una marca de tiempo, dado eso revisa los tipos de datos apropiados, posterior si la fecha la recuperas desde el cliente entonces mándala formateada de acuerdo con la estructura que espera tu base de datos, finalmente cuando la obtengas la puedes formatear tanto con lógica propia o a través de alguna biblioteca que implementes desde el cliente o el servidor

Comment: No se necesitaria guardar la fecha en un formato especial, basicamente puedes usar la funcion de fecha (como CURDATE() de mysql) en el insert. Al momento de generar el PDF puedes usar la funcion `setLocale()` y `date()` de PHP para formatearla en español o en cualquier idioma

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que estas haciendo esto:

```
$fecha= "<script> document.writeln(fecha_completa); </script>";
```

si quieres que se guarde en la DB y se Vea por pantalla deves hacer esto:

```
$fecha   = "<script> document.writeln(fecha_completa); </script>";
$fechadb = "fecha_completa";
```

y tu query debería ser:

```
$resultado = $conn->query("
    INSERT INTO datos_usuarios (
        nombre,
        apellido,
        curp,
        curso,
        horas,
        email,
        fecha
    ) VALUES (
        '$nombre',
        '$apellido',
        '$curp',
        '$curso',
        '$horas',
        '$email',
        '$fechadb'  // este es el cambio
    )");
```